# Set forceBackendUrlToFrontendUrl from KeyCloak by using Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak

It is possible to set `forceBackendUrlToFrontendUrl` as an environment variable in Kubernetes?

My problem is that the backend communication from pod to pod is over unencrypted HTTP.  Keycloak (frontend) is only reachable over HTTPS.

The JWT has the `"iss"` claim `https://......`, and the service calls Keycloak to check this token.  Keycloak says the token is invalid because the `"issues"` is invalid - and yes, it is right, `https` is not `http`.

I think i must set the variable `forceBackendUrlToFrontendUrl` from the Keycloak documentation, but I have no idea how I can set this in Kubernetes.

Comment: Did you found a solution to this problem ? I am in the same situation

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem, configuration below is working for me:

```
Keycloak:
Outside: https://keycloak.mydomain.com
Inside: https://keycloak.namespace.svc:8443

- Keycloak Container Env variables:
      env:
        - name: PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING
          value: "true"
        - name: KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL
          value: https://keycloak.mydomain.com/auth/

---

Frontend:
Outside: https://myfrontend.com
Inside: http://myfrontend.namespace.svc:8080

- Keycloak.json:  "url": "https://keycloak.mydomain.com/auth",

- Keycloak Admin Console:
  - frontend-client: RootURL: https://myfrontend.com

---

Backend:
Outside: https://myfrontend.com/api
Inside: http://mybackend.namespace.svc:8080

- Keycloak Admin Console:
  - backend-client: RootURL: http://mybackend.namespace.svc:8080

This is a spring boot application:
- application.yml
spring
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          keycloak:
            authorization-uri: "https://keycloak.mydomain.com/auth/realms/<realm>/protocol/openid-connect/auth"
            jwk-set-uri: "https://keycloak.namespace.svc:8443/auth/realms/<realm>/protocol/openid-connect/certs"
            token-uri: "https://keycloak.namespace.svc:8443/auth/realms/<realm>/protocol/openid-connect/token"
            user-info-uri: "https://keycloak.namespace.svc:8443/auth/realms/<realm>/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo"
            issuer-uri: "https://keycloak.mydomain.com/auth/realms/<realm>"
```